# Why the URL class does not support setting username for protocols other than http(s)?

Tags: javascript, url, ecmascript-6, browser

Consider the following code:

```js
const url = new URL('mumble://example.com');
url.username = 'user';
console.log(url.toString()); // prints "mumble://example.com"
```

But the same code works for http:

```js
const url = new URL('http://example.com');
url.username = 'user';
console.log(url.toString()); // prints "http://user@example.com/"
```

I couldn't find anything about that behaviour in the documentation. The workaround for my goal is funny:

```js
const url = new URL('mumble://example.com');
const protocol = url.protocol;
url.protocol = 'http:';
url.username = 'user';
url.protocol = protocol;
console.log(url.toString()); // prints "mumble://user@example.com/"
```

Can anyone be so kind to explain this?

edit: interestingly, the URL class does not support setting more properties as long as the protocol is not http or https:

```js
const url = new URL('mumble://example.com');
const protocol = url.protocol;
url.username = 'user';
url.pathname = 'foo';
url.port = 21;
url.protocol = protocol;
url.host = 'foo.bar';
console.log(url.toString()); // still mumble://example.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `URL` class in Firefox and Chrome to not fully conform to [the URL spec](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/), so the answer to your question is that the `URL` class's specification *does* allow this, but the environment you are running your code in does not follow the spec yet.

For example, running your example code in Node 14.x does output `mumble://user@example.com` as you were hoping it would.

Your options are to either work around the current behavior in the environments you support, or else to load a polyfill like [`whatwg-url`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-url) that would allow you to use the `URL` API as you expect.

Comment: [FF bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1374505) and [Chromium's](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=869291)

Answer (score 0):

Not all schemes support user names. For example, `file` doesn't. Your JS engine apparently assumes unknown schemes don't support user names.

Comment: The behaviour is the same on Firefox and on Chrome. Setting protocol before altering other properties of the URL works like a charm.

Comment: JS engine has nothing to do with that, it's a webAPI defined by whatwg and also implemented by node: it's an environment thing. And the specs are very clear that any scheme not in [this list](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#special-scheme) can't be used as base url, and that "*A URL **cannot have a username/password/port** if its host is null or the empty string, its cannot-be-a-base-URL flag is set, or its scheme is "file".*". So it's just entirely per specs.

Comment: Re "*Js engine has nothi g to do with that*", Except for the fact that it's the engine's library you're using...

Comment: @Kaiido, Re "*A URL cannot have a username/password/port if its host is null or the empty string*", I saw that, but the url being asked about has a host that is neither null nor an empty string.. If you can show where the spec considers `example.com` to not be a host, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: No it's not the js engine at all... it's the env. I.e it's not v8 or spidermonkey it's Blink and node or gecko. And for the specs, please read my comment again, a url that has a scheme which is not listed in the link I gave cannot be used as base url, which is a prerequisite to have user/password/port.

Comment: Gecko might be the one providing the code to the JS engine, but that doesn't affect what I said. The JS engine in the browser provides a URL class to JS code running within. I never said it was Spidermonkey; it's the instance of Spidermonkey in the browser. The instance of an engine is an engine. You're actually making my point for me: It's not part of the JS spec; it's merely something provided by the engine.

Comment: Re "*please read my comment again*", Yeah, it doesn't answer my question. I have absolutely no problems quoting the spec, but I'm not going to quote you. That's why I need the relevant parts of the spec.

Comment: @Kaiido, Re "*And the specs are very clear that any scheme not in this list can't be used as base url,*", Can't find what you claim. The passage you quote said it can't have a username if its cannot-be-a-base-URL flag is set. But that flag should not be set for `mumble://...` because the `:` is followed by `/`. (It would normally be set in [Parsing algorithm](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-parsing), *scheme state* state, step 2.9, but it only gets as far as 2.8). So I ask where this is stated

Comment: Yes my bad I misread that part, this URL can be used as a base.